# How to download specific jar from company repository, remaining jars from Maven repository

Tags: settings, maven-3, pom.xml

Our company is having own jar like retail.jar in our local repository, URL is http://localoff.com/public/releases. I want to download only/this specific retail.jar from our local repository. Remaining all other jars like spring.jar, commons.jar from maven central repository. How to configure in my maven settings.xml. All I want is my company jar(Only one jar) should download from local repository URL not from system, all other jars should download from Maven. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance
Rekha